# Some wrong with fwrite() in c++

Tags: c++, fwrite

I'm wrote function which count time of multiplying matrix. That is code:

```
if ((file = fopen("../logs.txt","w")) != NULL)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {   
        if(QueryPerformanceCounter(&start) !=0)
        {
            mult(m1, m2, m3);
            QueryPerformanceCounter(&finish);
            double temp = (double)(finish.QuadPart - start.QuadPart)/frequency.QuadPart;
            if(temp<=min || min == 0)
                min = temp;
        }
    }
    fwrite(&min, sizeof(min), 1, file);
    fclose(file);   
}
```

When i debug it, I saw that my min time equal 0.26336317888614069, but in file it was written "2W<сЪР?". Tell me please what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing the binary representation to the file, rather than the human-readable one.

Use:

```
fprintf(file, "%f", min);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing to file using `fprintf(file, "%f", min);` or something similar (`lf` instead of `f`, etc).

You wrote the binary representation of the value using `fwrite` but you want the decimal representation.

Should you use a `hexdump` over the file and interpret the result according to the floating point standards, you'll get back you expected number.

Answer (score 0):

`fwrite` will write the binary representation of the `double`, which are some characters that with no sense.

You can use `fprintf` instead.

`fprintf(file, "%lf", min)`